# How to use Python virtual environment on shared hosting for cron jobs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, virtualenv

Sorry if my question sounds dumb.

So I am following [A2Hosting guide](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connecting-to-mysql-using-python) to use Python 2.7. Now I want to use Python2.7 for Cronjob purpose. How can I use Virtual Environment for Cronjob? Is there a way to keep virtual environment active all the time or I need to make some Bash script to activate virtual environment first and then run `python` command?

Comment: Just run `/path/to/venv/bin/python your_programm.py`.

Answer (score 0):

activate your virtual environment:

```
source ./VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/activate
```

or if you are using virtual env wrapper:

```
workon VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME
```

now you can get your path to python in virtual env by executing:

```
which python
```

when you get absolute path to python you can call your script from cron using your virtual env:

```
/path/to/python /path/to/your/script.py
```